# Migration eclipse rcp 3.x to 4

Tags: css, eclipse, migration, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to migrate the **eclipse rcp 3.x application to 4** .This is very big application . What will be the proper steps to migrate this?

Thanks
Alok Kumar Singh

Comment: This is far too broad. Eclipse 4 still supports Eclipse 3 style RCPs. So try building it with Eclipse 4 - note that [tag:tycho] with [tag:maven] is now the only supported RCP build method.

Comment: In addition what greg-449 said, see the [Plug-in Migration Guide](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/nav/2_3).

Comment: Since 4.x comes with a compatibility layer allowing 3.x plugins to run to 4.x, the best way to start is to do just what @greg-449 wrote - build it with Eclipse 4.x. There are some articles about this topic around (google it), e.g. this one discusses your options: https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2016/01/08/migrating-from-eclipse-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/